# How to remove middle numbers in PinFieldAutoFill flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, validation, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

When I entering an OTP it continuously adding numbers from the beginning but how do I change the middle number from entered 6 digit OTP
I have used this in Model Bottom Sheet

Column(
children: [
SizedBox(
height: 50,
child: PinFieldAutoFill(
textInputAction: TextInputAction.previous,
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
autoFocus: true,
focusNode: FocusNode(),
cursor: Cursor(
width: 2,
height: 40,
color: Colors.red,
radius: const Radius.circular(5),
enabled: true,
),
decoration: UnderlineDecoration(
textStyle: const TextStyle(
fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
colorBuilder: FixedColorBuilder(
Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3)),
),
currentCode: code,
codeLength: 6,
onCodeSubmitted: (verificationCode) {
debugPrint("CURRENT CODE CHANGES 2: " +
verificationCode.toString());
otpNumber = verificationCode;
},
onCodeChanged: (verificationCode) {
debugPrint("CURRENT CODE CHANGES 3: " +
verificationCode.toString());
if (verificationCode.toString().length == 6) {
// FocusScope.of(context)
//     .requestFocus(FocusNode());
setState(() {
code = verificationCode.toString();
otpNumber = verificationCode.toString();
});
}
},
),
// child: OtpTextField(
//   onSubmit: (String verificationCode) {
//     setState(() {
//       otpNumber = verificationCode;
//       debugPrint(otpNumber);
//     });
//   },
//   cursorColor: primaryDarkColor,
//   numberOfFields: 6,
//   borderColor: primaryDarkColor,
//   focusedBorderColor: primaryColor,
//   enabledBorderColor: primaryDarkColor,
//   fillColor: hintColor,
//   borderWidth: 2.0,
//   fieldWidth: 40,
//   mainAxisAlignment:
//       MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
//   filled: true,
//   showFieldAsBox: true,
//   textStyle: kkTitleTextStyle,
// ),
),
const SizedBox(height: 20),
SizedBox(
height: 45,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.43,
child: ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () {
verify();
},
child: const Text('Submit OTP'),
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
horizontal: 20.0),
primary: primaryDarkColor,
textStyle: kkTitleTextStyle,
),
),
),
const SizedBox(height: 20),
isResend
? const Center(
child: Text(
'Didn't  receive any OTP ?',
style: kkMediumGrayTextStyle,
),
)
: const Center(
child: Text(
'',
style: kkMediumGrayTextStyle,
),
),
const SizedBox(height: 5),
isResend
? GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
setModalState(() {
if (_controller.isCompleted) {
fetchOtp(phoneNumberController.text
.toString());
_controller = AnimationController(
duration:
const Duration(seconds: 30),
vsync: this);
_controller.forward();
isResend = false;
} else {
debugPrint('TIME IS RUNNING');
}
debugPrint(
'VALUE: ${_controller.value}');
debugPrint(
'STATUS: ${_controller.status}');

```
                                    debugPrint(
                                        'IS_ANIMATING: ${_controller.isAnimating}');

                                    debugPrint(
                                        'IS_COMPLETED: ${_controller.isCompleted}');
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    const Text(
                                      'Resend OTP',
                                      style: kkTitleTextStyle,
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                    CountDown(
                                      animation: StepTween(
                                        begin: 30,
                                        end: 0,
                                      ).animate(_controller),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            : GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  // setState(() {
                                  //   if (_controller.isCompleted) {
                                  //     fetchOtp(
                                  //         phoneNumberController.text.toString());
                                  //     _controller = AnimationController(
                                  //         duration: const Duration(seconds: 30),
                                  //         vsync: this);
                                  //     _controller.forward();
                                  //   } else {
                                  //     debugPrint('TIME IS RUNNING');
                                  //   }
                                  //
                                  // });
                                  debugPrint('VALUE: ${_controller.value}');
                                  debugPrint(
                                      'STATUS: ${_controller.status}');
                                  debugPrint(
                                      'IS_ANIMATING: ${_controller.isAnimating}');
                                  debugPrint(
                                      'IS_COMPLETED: ${_controller.isCompleted}');
                                },
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    const Text(
                                      'Seconds Remaining',
                                      style: kkTitleTextStyle,
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                    CountDown(
                                      animation: StepTween(
                                        begin: 30,
                                        end: 0,
                                      ).animate(_controller),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                      ],
                    )
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet ? You can check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.